# Web application - multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, web-applications, concurrency

Tell me, please, is there a guarantee that one thread will perform one task and will not switch to another during the execution of the current one? (I.e. pseudo-parallelism). That is, until this task is completed, the thread will not be released. At the same time, the system has two cores.
Also interested in why Tomcat has 200 threads by default if we have 2 cores (and *2 => 4 threads). What's the difference? With 4 threads, it will not be possible to ensure optimal operation of more than 1000 users...?

Comment: There is no guarantee that a thread will not be paused while another is executed. Cores and threads are different things, or at least the meanings get mixed up depending on what the context is. Each core (physical or logical) only process one thing at a time, however, a system can still have thousands of threads waiting to be executed, and the scheduler decides which one gets executed in which order.

Comment: Threads spend time blocked in IO, so having more threads than CPUs increases throughput, when using the model of a single thread dedicated to each request.

Comment: What you are concerning is something that Sping WebFlux/Vertx/Netty trying to solve -non-blocking

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two contexts: One thread might well be interrupted any time - or just wait for I/O to complete. During this time, *the CPU core* might execute another thread (or totally different process).

From within the thread, you'll always be in the same context, no switching appears. Other than executions possibly taking more or less time, the thread itself does not notice that it's interrupted. A thread is an abstraction for developing software, so that you're decoupled from context switches on the CPU.

Possible interruptions also explain why Webservers typically allocate *a lot* more threads for simultaneous executions than a machine has cores.

My expectation is that a webserver's default settings do not quite provide *optimal* resource allocations, but for most intents and purposes are a reasonable default, from which you might want to divert based on the characteristics of your application. e.g. if you're doing heavy CPU work without any I/O, your optimal setting will differ from an application with heavy I/O and minor CPU usage.

So, for application development purposes: A thread will execute exactly one task - interruption doesn't matter as it's transparent to the executed code. You might want to measure and tune your system and set optimal values rather than the default - but most of the times the webserver's default values are a better starting point than the number of your CPU cores.